# How to show existing appstore apps link in a new iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I want to show many iPhone apps related to me in table view with wrapped in LinkShare and TradeDoubler account, due to which when any purchase made, gives me commission. I have seen in some apps with More great Apps button which opens a link in web view to show many apps in table view after clicking one of them a link of iTunes app store will open and if you purchase any app then commission goes to app owner.

I have attached the screen shot to clear it quickly -
any help would be greatly appreciated,Thanks

[image]

Comment: There is a problem with this. Do you plan to release this app? Because Apple has recently changed their terms and conditions and a new rule is that you are not allowed to promote any other apps in any way in your own app. So sorry about this, but Apple would reject the app

Comment: Can you please share that page where Apple has mentioned this?

Comment: http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/10/01/apples-updated-app-store-terms-could-kill-app-promotion-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file and place it in a server with your URL stored in it (you can add metadata, imageURL, ...)
Then in your app, if you have access to internet display the tableview with the data loaded from the file. If you have not access to it or if it's corrupted, present a view with something else. You can also use this placeholder for the Apple validation according to TeenDev answer ;-)